# How to retrieve all *.html files from website using Unix command line tools and regular expression

Tags: mac, unix, html, wget, curl

I would like to retrieve all .html files from a website that has a certain text on its name:

eg. this_is_good_site.html

So, I would like to download .html files with a word "good" on its name. I tried wget and curl, but I did not understand how can I choose those files using a regular expression? Is there a Python or Perl solution, if command line tools on Unix can't do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you're wanting to do it with Python you might look into using [urlib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) - you would also probably have better luck with this question on [StackOverflow.](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 2):

As you're using a Unix environment, try this using wget's [Recursive Accept/Reject Options](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Recursive-Accept_002fReject-Options.html);

```
wget -r -A "*good*" <site_to_download>
```

This will perform a recursive (-r) download of the site, and only accept (-A) paths which match the pattern ("*good*")

Answer (score 1):

Try HTTrack website copier or a similar program, better than command line. download it all to a directory, sort by .html copy and paste them all somewhere else, delete the leftovers

http://www.httrack.com/